# How do I split a single column into multiple rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I split this...

| A |
| --- |
| Pikachu |
| 5kg |
| Male |
|  |
| Snorlax |
| 100kg |
| Male |
|  |
| Raichu |
| 15kg |
| Female |

to this...

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pikachu | 5kg | Male |
| Snorlax | 100kg | Male |
| Raichu | 15kg | Female |

in Excel?

Comment: *How do I split this...* You can use formulas, power query or VBA.  What version of Excel will you be using?  Please show what you have tried.  And is there an empty row between each group of three?

Answer (score 0):

Select your data.  `Copy` it.  Go to cell you want to paste.  Click on `Paste special` then click `transpose`.

Comment: Wont' that only result in a single row?  And not three rows as he shows?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Exactly. It needs to be done one by one for each group of three rows.  I thought the owner of the question does not aware of this type of paste special operation (transpose) and just wanted to aware him/her.

Answer (score 0):

According to the row number of source data and the result cells, I suggest you use [index function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd).

If there are spaces between each set of data, you can try the following formula on my sample.

For name, the cells of source data are A1, A5, A9, the result cells are D1, D2, D3, then we could use "Row(result cells)*4-3" to get the row number of source data.

`=IF(INDEX(A:A,ROW()*4-3)=0,"",INDEX(A:A,ROW()*4-3))`

[image]

The same way for weight:

`=IF(INDEX(A:A,ROW()*4-2)=0,"",INDEX(A:A,ROW()*4-2))`

[image]

The same way for gender:

`=IF(INDEX(A:A,ROW()*4-1)=0,"",INDEX(A:A,ROW()*4-1))`

[image]